# You see a picture of a woman with a phone in her hand and I ask

Tags: grammar

You see a picture of a woman with a phone in her hand, and you ask about this impossible situation.

- "How was she able to take a photo with her phone if she had it in her hand?"
- "How could she have taken a photo with her phone if she had it in her hand?"
- "How could she take a photo with her phone if she had it in her hand?"
- "How had she been able to take a photo with her phone if she had it in her hand?"

Comment: Please could you include your research? Which do you think is correct and why are you unsure?

Comment: I think it's this one.
"How could she take a photo with her phone if she had it in her hand?"

Comment: The picture, in itself, tells you very little; there is context that is necessary in order to determine the tense. The cases differ in pairs with the  particularity that the ones use the past simple whereas the others the pluperfect.

Comment: All sound grammatical to me meaning mostly the same thing but with their very very fine individual nuances (maybe the last one I wouldn't prefer as it is a bit convoluted

Comment: https://photos5.appleinsider.com/gallery/25816-35732-DbkfWafW0AEdKQc-xl.jpg

Gal Gadot is advertising Huawei, but the twitt is sent from an iPhone. She couldn't take a photo with Huawei because this phone it's in the picture.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you asking which is grammatical? Which is most natural? What best fits the situation you refer to? What the differences in meaning are? All these are different questions.

Comment: I'm asking about the situation in the photo I added. How would you say it?

Comment: I'd say "How is her phone in the picture if she's supposed to have taken the picture with it? And how can she pose herself and frame the shot if she's using a mirror when she can't see the screen?" The problem isn't that the phone is in her hand but that the phone is in the picture. However this isn't really a question about the English language so is off-topic as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Thank you for your time.